# Tagline Added to Squarespace OM shifts position at different screen widths

Tags: css, squarespace

I need to create a tagline under the logo for Squarespace OM, and I can't create a text block there so I created one lower on the page and used CSS to position it near the top of the page. However, the tagline only stays in place at 1816 width screen size and above even though I am using CSS that I thought would work to keep the tagline under the logo at non-mobile screen sizes. At other screen sizes the tagline appears above the logo/navigation. (At mobile size, tagline can go away.) The site is here: https://shara-karasic-rkbg.squarespace.com/

How can I make sure the tagline stays in a fixed position under the logo at tablet and desktop sizes?

The CSS I used is:

```
     @media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
       /* Add your custom styles here for Desktop */
         #block-yui_3_17_2_2_1516902907408_4620{color:
    #5b01a6;position: relative;padding: 0 0 0 5;bottom:2300px;}
     }
 @media only screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
   /* Add your custom styles here for Tablet */
     #block-yui_3_17_2_2_1516902907408_4620{color:
#5b01a6;position: relative;padding: 0 0 0 5;bottom:2300px;}
 }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The right position for your text-block html would be inside of the <div id="lower-logo"> Tag. But I think you are not able to change the html structure in Squarespace, are you? If not, the only solution I could think of is Javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#lower-logo").append('<p class="tagline">Merging mind-body...</p>');
});
```

You can then easily position / style your new element with CSS and it will always stay next to the logo.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that a way around not being able to easily add a tagline directly below the logo/navigation in Squarespace OM was to delete the template's header image (header image is right below the logo/navigation) and instead add a new image to the main content area using the image block, with a markdown block above it that contains a formatted tagline. Then I just had to remove some extra space above the markdown block using some custom css. Reducing the margin-top on #page did the trick to tighten up the extra whitespace:

```
#page {margin-top:13px}
```